# " Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Tags: javascript, ajax, vb.net, web-services

I really can't understand what is Exact problem here while calling the web service in the html page with JavaScript using ajax as it produces the error below:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Ajax Code:

```js
function Image() {
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "WebService.asmx/GetImage",
        data: "{'sDB': '" + "sDB" + "'}", 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnGetMemberSuccess,
        failure: function (errMsg) {
            $('#errorMessage').text(errMsg);  //errorMessage is id of the  div
        }
    });
    function OnGetMemberSuccess(data, status) {
        alert("data" + data.d);
        $("#MemberDetails").html(data.d);
        $('input[type=button]').attr('disabled', false);
    }
}
```

Where sDB is Null.

Button click code:

```html
<input type="button" id="Button" value="Image" onclick="Image()" />
```

I have used the same code in my previous projects but its working fine.

Web service code:

```
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> <WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetImage()

    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
    Dim con = New SqlConnection("server = PROG19-PC;database = XIDBViews;Trusted_Connection = yes")
    cmd.Connection = con
    con.Open()
    Dim strQuery As String = ""
    Dim oSB As New StringBuilder
    Dim table As New Table()
    Dim tr As New TableRow()
    Dim td As New TableCell()
    Dim sFirstNameValue As String = String.Empty
    Dim sLastNameValue As String = String.Empty
    Dim DoBValue As String = String.Empty
    Dim sPhoto As String = String.Empty

    strQuery = "SELECT [sFirstName],[sLastName],[DoB],[sPhoto] FROM [XIDBViews].[dbo].[tblEmployee]  "
    cmd = New SqlCommand(strQuery, con)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
    oSB.Append("<table><thead><tr><th>" + " FirstName" + "</th><th>" + "Lastname" + "</th><th>" + "DoB" + "</th><th>" + "Party" + "</th><th>" + "Photo" + "</th></tr></thead>")
    While dr.Read()
        sFirstNameValue = dr("sFirstName").ToString
        sLastNameValue = dr("sLastName").ToString
        DoBValue = dr("DoB").ToString
        sPhoto = dr("sPhoto").ToString

        oSB.Append("<tbody id=tbodyid'>")

        oSB.Append("<tr>")
        oSB.Append("<td class=border1>")
        oSB.Append(sFirstNameValue)
        oSB.Append("</td>")

        oSB.Append("<td class=border1 >")
        oSB.Append(sLastNameValue)
        oSB.Append("</td>")

        oSB.Append("<td  class=border1>")
        oSB.Append(DoBValue)
        oSB.Append("</td>")

        oSB.Append("<td class=border1>")
        oSB.Append(sPhoto)
        oSB.Append("</td>")

        oSB.Append("</tr>")
        oSB.Append("</tbody>")
    End While
    dr.Close()
    con.Close()
    MsgBox(oSB.ToString)
    'Debug.Print(oSB.ToString)
    Return oSB.ToString()
End Function
End Class
```

But this web service code is working fine and according to my knowledge problem is with the ajax code, can anyone please help me with this.
Cheers.

Comment: A javascript error on client side can not cause 500, because as the code status indicates, it's an _internal server error_. There MUST be something wrong on your server side.

Comment: `data: "{'sDB': '" + "sDB" + "'}"` this line will ends up as `data:"{'sDB': 'sDB'}"`, **literally**. Is that what you really mean?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i tried with this and its not working for me.

Comment: No, I was asking/informing you, that the `data` part may not work as you expected, is the string **literal** really what you want?

Comment: yes. I tried passing the values to the query in the  web service and it dint work for me, so i tried static way.

Comment: Try to debug your server side code.

Comment: I tried it. In the  chrome's debugging mode i clicked on the link (http://localhost:50017/WebService.asmx/GetFirst) next to the error message by setting the break point in the web service and now its executed and got the output in the message box,But i cant pass this values back in order to display it inside the div in html page.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try to insert the URL you are requesting directly into the browser ...
You will receive an error message telling you that ,

**"Only Web services with a [ScriptService] attribute on the class definition can be called from script"**

add the [ScriptService] attribute to the top of your service class definition, and it may solve your problem.

I had a similar problem and It worked for me :D

Answer (score 0):

Changing datatype from json to text fixed my problem